# Using intent defined in attrs.xml to be able to launch a custom activity

Tags: android

I am extending ConstraintLayout to be able to make something custom and would like to get activity launch intent from outside class or layout.xml and start that activity when this custom view is clicked. I know how to make icon and a text as an attribute but do not know how to make the Intent an attribute. Following is what I have currently. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class MyGridDelegate extends ConstraintLayout implements View.OnClickListener {

    private String text;
    private Drawable icon;
    private Intent link;
    
    public MyGridDelegate (...)
    {
        TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyGridLayoutDelegate, defStyle, 0);

        String text = a.getString(R.styleable.MyGridLayoutDelegate_text);
        Drawable icon = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.MyGridLayoutDelegate_icon);
        Intent link = .....; // *********Intent is missing*********
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Launch some activity that is received as attribute
        MyGridDelegate.this.startActivity(this.link);
    }
}
```

attrs.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="MyGridDelegate">
        <attr name="text" format="string" />
        <attr name="icon" format="integer" />
        <attr name="link" format="******dont know*****" />
</declare-styleable>
```

layout_main.xml

```
<vendor.xxxx.yyy.MyGridLayout
        style="@style/MyGridLayoutStyle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

        <vendor.xxxx.yyy.MyGridLayoutDelegate
            style="@style/MyGridLayoutDelegateStyle"
            app:icon="@drawable/settings_bl_icon"
            app:text="Bluetooth"
            app:link="****dont know*****"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I can pass the activity name to be launched as string. Then do something like this:

```
       setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClassName(getContext(), m_link);
            getContext().startActivity(intent);
        });
```